# PlayWright HTML report serving not working in docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, playwright

I am running my PlayWright tests from a docker container to test my ReactJS app
Everything works, a directory for the report is generated
In the case some tests fail, PlayWright tries to serve the report on port 9323

[image]

The port is bound to localhost on the same port:[image]

And I expect it to fail to open it on the browser since it's inside a container
But when I try browse to localhost:9323 what I got back is the following:[image]

**Base docker image:** `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-focal`

**Node.js version:** 14.20.1

##### PlayWright Config

```json
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { devices } from '@playwright/test';

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
// require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: './tests',
  /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
  timeout: 30 * 1000,
  expect: {
    /**
     * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
     * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
     */
    timeout: 5000
  },
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : 1,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./tests/global-setup'),
  use: {
    /* Maximum time each action such as `click()` can take. Defaults to 0 (no limit). */
    actionTimeout: 0,
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on',
    storageState: 'storageState.json',
    locale: 'en-US',
    timezoneId: 'UTC',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      },
    },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: {
    //     ...devices['Pixel 5'],
    //   },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: {
    //     ...devices['iPhone 12'],
    //   },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: {
    //     channel: 'msedge',
    //   },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: {
    //     channel: 'chrome',
    //   },
    // },
  ],

  /* Folder for test artifacts such as screenshots, videos, traces, etc. */
  // outputDir: 'test-results/',

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  // webServer: {
  //   command: 'npm run start',
  //   port: 3000,
  // },
};

export default config;
```

##### Tried

Ran `npx playwright test`
One test failed which triggered the serving of HTML report when the tests finished
Browsed to `http://localhost:9323` like it told me to do
Got empty response

##### Expected

Getting a page that looks like the following, containing the test report -

[image]

##### Workaround

Mount report directory to a host directory and running `npx playwright show-report` on it
Although this works, this method is cumbersome when doing multiple times

Answer (score 1):

The hostname is now a settable flag:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/16667

Try setting your hostname to 0.0.0.0 when calling npx playwright show-report:

```
npx playwright show-report --host 0.0.0.0
```

You'll still get an error about it being unable to open a browser, but, for me, I am now able to get to the HTML report from the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to either :

- expose the port of the container for it to be accessible from the outside
- map a container port to a host port for the container port to be accessible via the host port

`docker container run -d --expose 3000 -p 80:8080`

Here you're :

- exposing the port 3000 of the container and
- mapping the host port 80 to the container port 8080

Answer (score 0):

To avoid opening of html-report when running on container use this in the config file:

```
reporter: process.env.CI ? [ ['html', { open: 'never'}] ] : [ ['html'] ],
```

When you run your tests in container, you need to pass the value "true" to the CI-env and then run the tests:

```
export CI=true
npx playwright test
```